# Bootstrap Sass Color change JS

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to change bootstrap sass colors with a click of a button? I tried googling but I didn't find anything. Thanks for any help <3

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change bootstrap colors with a click of button in whole Sass file because it's not used in browser, It can't be done in CSS file globally if color is directly applied to properties.

But you can modify it if it's a CSS variable, a CSS variable looks like this

--theme-color : blue;

That might be possible if you are using preprocessors in Browser, less.js works in browser but I am not sure if you can change value of variable with a click in less.

I think you should review what you are actually creating.